# How to "Stop the dynamically changing top value during scroll" in css

Tags: html, css, css-position

1. In my page I have a Settings icon, when I click that icon a list box appears at the bottom of the icon.
2. The top value of the list box getting changed based on the scrolling of  page.
3. How to stop this dynamically changing top value.

```html
.listbox{
    top: 657px;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
    left: 853.234px;
    right: auto;
    }
```

Comment: can you add more relevant code or a rough drawing of what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

change
`position: absolute;`
to
`position: fixed;`